# Trying to skip SecurityUtils in a Unit Test

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a unit test for a method which calls `SecurityUtils.getCurrntUser()` to create an Object User.

When i try this:

```
//User testUser = new User();
testUser.setId(1L)
 
Mockito.when(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUser()).thenReturn(testUser);
```

it throws an error that

> Mockito cannot mock private final classes.

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: please add some context to your problem, like where does SecurityUtils comes from, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: To mock `final` method, you have to use *PowerMock* instead

Comment: We would need mot context. If currentUser is static and/or final, and what Mockito version are you using. Because it seems you are trying to mock a static method, but this is not the way, you'd require `Mockito.mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class)`, but it is only available from v3.4.x

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.